# Image error with "~" symbol

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am facing a problem with images in my pages.  In my data base I mentioned the image path like:

```
"/images/smallimages/sandal1.png "
```

It's working fine and displaying the image in my view on my local host but after uploading the code to the server the images are not displaying.  Do I need to place the tilde(~) symbol in the image URL?.  And I am binding image path like below:

```
<a href="@Html.DisplayFor(m=>m.larImagePath1)" class="MagicZoom" id="Zoomer" rel="selectors-effect-speed:100">
    <img src="@Html.DisplayFor(m=>m.medImagePath1)" /></a><br/>
<!-- selector with own title -->
<a href="@Html.DisplayFor(m=>m.larImagePath1)" rel="zoom-id:Zoomer;" rev="@Html.DisplayFor(m=>m.medImagePath1)">
    <img src="@Html.DisplayFor(m=>m.smaImagePath1)"/></a>
<!-- selector without title and with own zoom window size -->
<a href="@Html.DisplayFor(m=>m.larImagePath2)" rel="zoom-id:Zoomer;selectors-effect-speed: 200" rev="@Html.DisplayFor(m=>m.medImagePath2)">
    <img src="@Html.DisplayFor(m=>m.smaImagePath2)"/></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the `Url.Content` helper for image URLs, like so:

```
<img src='@Url.Content("~" + Model.smaImagePath1)' />
```

Comment: I fixed my self.And nice solution by asymptotic.